# AEM Sling update property from within model

Tags: properties, model, resources, aem, sling

```
@Self
Resource resource;

@Inject
@Named(value = "key")
private String key;

@PostConstruct
protected void init() throws PersistenceException {
        ResourceResolver rr = resource.getResourceResolver();
        ModifiableValueMap map = resource.adaptTo(ModifiableValueMap.class);
        String value = fetchValue();
        map.put("key", value);
        rr.commit();
    }
```

I'm trying to give the property "Key" the default value "value". Unfortunately it has to be returned by a function and can't be simply set to a primitive type with @Default(..). The above code seems to do nothing, the value of the component is not updated. I'm pretty new to the whole AEM stack so I feel like I might be going at this the wrong way.

Comment: to understand it correctly, you inject from the JCR a value into key?
From JCR only primitive types are returned and can be represented with value. Is it more likely that you load sub-nodes and stuff? 
Maybe it helps if you post what kind of data you want to retrieve from JCR - key of type String is very vague

Answer (score 1):

Please remove revolver.commit() line . Unless you’ve obtained the resolver using the system user , you don’t have to commit it . You can simple use Session session=resolver.adaptTo(Session.class)  and then say session.save ().

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the value of the field `key` to the value you were trying to fetch instead of modifying the JCR property value directly?

```
@Inject
private String key;

@PostConstruct
protected void init() {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(key)) {
        key = fetchValue();
    }
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}
```

On a different note, the `@Self` injector is discouraged due to reasons mentioned [here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#a-note-about-cache-true-and-using-the-self-injector).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was using the @PostConstruct wrong: I thought it would trigger upon creation of the node, but the trigger is instead related to the rendering of the component.

Answer (score 0):

To set values in a sling model when rendering a component is an anti-pattern. The repository shouldn't be modified when the page is being rendered. If you need to have default values when component node is created use **cq:template** feature of AEM. This copies over properties defined in the template when a new component instance is created. [template != page template in this context]

Its usage has been answered in this question [AEM DefaultValue written to JCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631381/aem-defaultvalue-written-to-jcr/30634082#30634082)

Additional reference :

http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/defaults-in-your-component/